# Python 3.6 looking in wrong module/library ( _io.TextIOWrapper ) for function that should be called from pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I am getting the following error from the code that follows, below:

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'write_text'

Code:

```
import pathlib
output_filepath = pathlib.Path(r'/home/john/somedir/data/somefilename.csv')
with output_filepath.open(mode='w') as output_file:
    for line in result_list:
        # Write records to the file
        output_file.write_text('%s\n' % line[1])
```

"result_list" comes from a result_list = cursor.fetchall()

The weird thing is this code is cut-and-pasted from a program that does not produce this error.  Nothing is touching the object "output_filepath" in between when it gets instantiated and when it gets used in the "with" block.

I have searched The Google for the error and get zero hits (which was very surprising to me).  I also looked over the various hits here (stackoverflow) that come up when you enter your "subject" for a new question.

I originally had "from pathlib import Path" as my import line, but changed it (along with the "output_filepath = ..." line) to what you see here, in my quest to find the problem.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong somewhere, but I don't see what it is, and I don't understand why the code would work in the other program but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two objects `output_filepath` and `output_file` in your codes have different classes/types, and because of that they have different methods you can use.

You tried to use `write_text`, which is a method of the `pathlib.Path` object. However, when you're calling `output_filepath.open(mode='w')` you are getting an *open file object* in return. You can see it - Python says its type is `_io.TextIOWrapper` in the error message. Hence `output_file.write_text` doesn't work.

This open file object does not have a `write_text` method, but does have the `write` method that most files or file-like objects have in Python.

So this works:

```
import pathlib
output_filepath = pathlib.Path(r'/home/john/somedir/data/somefilename.csv')
with output_filepath.open(mode='w') as output_file:
    for line in result_list:
        # Write records to the file
        output_file.write('%s\n' % line[1])
```

Comment: You're right, output_file.write() works, but I am unclear under what circumstances I could/should use .write_text().  I guess it's really a moot point since I now have code that works, but I would absolutely LOVE to better understand the use of .write() versus .write_text().  I've read everything I can find about .write_text() (I just started using pathlib last week), but I don't think I yet understand it very well.

Comment: Sorry for not being short on explaining! I've updated the answer. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Thank you!  That's VERY helpful on the _io.TextIOWrapper side of the question and it is what I had assumed was going on.  The part I don't understand, is why isn't it calling the .open() method in pathlib.Path.  The object output_filepath is being instantiated as  a pathlib.Path object.  It seems as though that object would behave as it was instantiated and respond accordingly to the .open() call.

Again, I can't tell you how grateful I am for you taking the time you have to help me understand what's going on.